# Angular in Excel Import

Tags: angularjs, excel

I am trying to implement a function to get the value of a table from an Excel file in html.

In my excel-function.html I have:

```
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/master/FileSaver.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <button ng-click="exportData()" ng-show="(items|filter:{selected: true}).length">Export</button>
    <br />
    <table width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Terms</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
                    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.selected" /></td>
                    <td>{{item.Name}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.Date}}</td>
                    <td><span ng-repeat="term in item.Terms">{{term}}{{!$last?', ':''}}</span></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    <div id="exportable" style="display:none">
        <table width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Terms</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="item in items|filter:{selected: true}">
                    <td>{{item.Name}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.Date}}</td>
                    <td><span ng-repeat="term in item.Terms">{{term}}{{!$last?', ':''}}</span></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my excel-export.directive.js I have:

```
function myCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.exportData = function () {
        var blob = new Blob([document.getElementById('exportable').innerHTML], {
            type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=utf-8"
        });
        saveAs(blob, "Report.xls");
    };

    $scope.importData = function () {
        var obj = xlsx(file);

    }

    $scope.items = [{
        "Name": "ANC101",
            "Date": "10/02/2014",
            "Terms": ["samsung", "nokia", "apple"]
    }, {
        "Name": "ABC102",
            "Date": "10/02/2014",
            "Terms": ["motrolla", "nokia", "iPhone"]
    }]
}
```

But I do not know how to get the excel file in the angular.

I'm not sure I should be put on how td reads the excel file.

How to import an Excel file, you wonder if you can put the value of the file in scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across the same problem a few months ago, and I decided to create a library for this. Would you check it out? I appreciate your feedback as well as make myself available to help you!
https://github.com/Helvio88/angular-xlsx-model